# I need help figuring what wrong with my code! ('int' issue)

Tags: python, int

i am having an issue figuring out why my code is wrong.

```
def draw_poly(t, n, size):
for s in (n):
t.forward(sz)
t.left(45)

draw_poly (liz, 8, 50)
```

I am trying to make a octogon but it keeps on giving me an "'int' object is not iterable" error.

If you could help i would be forever grateful, Thanks.

Comment: Hello Julian. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Since you are new here, you should take a look at [help] and [ask] to learn how to craft an on-topic question. Generally, if you are asking for debugging help, you should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Julian. Since whitespace is significant in Python it's important that you reproduce your actual indentation when you ask questions here. You can paste code into your question from your text editor, then select it and press the `{}` button or Ctrl+K to indent the whole block by four spaces.

Comment: I sorry to say that googling "loop in python" would have helped you understanding what was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for-loop:

```
for s in (n):
```

Expects `n` to be some sort of iterable: a `list`, `tuple`, `dictionary`, etc, but you are passing an integer (`int`) - hence the error.

If you want `s` to take the values `0`, `1`, `2`, `...`, `n` then you should use the `range()` function to produce an iterable sequence of the numbers up to the number passed into it.

Therefore, what your probably want is:

```
for s in range(n):
```

which will allow you to work with an integer variable `s` in that code block.

---

If you want to debug your code, it often helps to print out the values of variables to check they are evaluating to what you think they should be.

For instance,

```
for i in range(4):
    print(i)
```

gives:

```
0
1
2
3
```

which is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

The correct int iterable would be range(int), so, use this: `for s in range(n):`

For the future using of `range()`: this function creates a list of iterable int objects. In some cases using of `xrange()` is better, especially for large loops. 
I.e. `range(1000000000)` creates a huge object in memory while `xrange(1000000000)` does not, though it works in a similar way giving you int numbers one by one.

Comment: the xrange vs range bit is only valid for python 2.